# Unity 3D Rigidbody AddForce does not work for me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**My script that is attached to a gameobject:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollideWith : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string type;
    public float jump_power;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (type == "jump_pad")
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("JUMPPAD");
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("PLAYER");
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, jump_power, 0), ForceMode.Force);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes the float `jump_power` has a value of 10f

Both "JUMPPAD" and "PLAYER" debugs are working correctly but the addforce is not.

Comment: you are applying 10kg of force to what?

Comment: **I found a solution:**

Just replaced the `AddForce(new Vector3(0, jump_power, 0), ForceMode.Force);`,

with `AddForce(new Vector3(0, jump_power, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);`

and it worked! Try that if you have trouble like I had.
So if you have `ForceMode.Force` change it with `ForceMode.Impulse`

I will not remove this post for anyone else with that 
[trouble.][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MYwd.jpg

Comment: @BugFinder To the player gameobject

Comment: I wasnt asking to what object i can see. But if you have a 100kg object 10g of force with normal resistance is not going to do jack